# Prove that $H$ is a finite set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, proof-verification

Let $H$ be compact in $\Bbb R^n$

Also assume that for every $x\in H$ there is an $r=r(x)$ such that $B_r(x)\cap H=\{x\} $

Prove that $H$ is a finite set.

---

**Solution:**

Since $H$ is compact, $\exists$ a finite $$x_1, x_2, \dots , x_N\in H \subseteq \bigcup B_{r(x_i)}$$

for $N\in\Bbb N$

Let's set $r:=$ min $\{r(x_1),\dots , r(x_N)\}$

Then, $$H \subseteq \bigcup _{i=1}^{N} B_r(x_i)$$

Then, $$( \bigcup _{i=1}^{N} B_r(x_i))\cap H= \{x_1, \dots ,x_N\}$$

So, $H=\{x_1,\dots , x_N\}$ is finite.

---

Does the proof of details true? Does there exist any drawbacks, missing in detail?

To learn this is important for me. I exhibited all my performance. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: I think you have some problems with notation here. You say that $r = r(x)$ and then later you define a different $r$. It's also ambiguous when you write $B_r (x_i)$ because it's not really clear that $r$ is evaluated at $x_i$ or some other point.

Comment: Please can you edit these on the question. I cannot see my notation mistakes. I am a new math student. Please:) @AlexStrife

Comment: It seems like you have chosen $r(x)$ depending on $x\in H$ such that $B_{r(x)}(x)\cap H=\{x\}$. Then you covered $H$ with the $B_{r(x)}(x)$ over all $x\in H$ and then used compactness to obtain $x_1,...,x_n$ such that $H$ is in the union of the $B_{r(x_i)}(x_i)$. If so, then you are finished and there is no need to take the minimum of the the radii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $H$ is not finite.  Then, there exists a sequence $(x_i) \in H$.  Since $H$ is compact by assumption, by Bolzano-Weierstrass, there is a convergent subsequence. Say, the subsequence is also called $(x_{i})$ which converges to a point $x$.  By definition of convergence, for every $\epsilon >0,$ there is an $N$ such that if $i > N$, then $|x - x_i| < \epsilon$.  But this is a contradiction to the hypothesis that $B_r(x) \cap H = x$ for $r$ small enough.  Thus, $H$ must be finite.

Comment: Is this enough to prove? Thank you. This proof is more easy than mine. Thank you:)

Answer (score 3):

The collection $\{ B_{r(x)} (x) \}$ (open balls of radius $r(x)$ and centered at $x$) forms an open cover of $H$. Since $H$ is compact, this collection has a finite subcover $\{ B_{r(x_i)} (x_i) \}_{i=1}^N$. Then you can proceed as you did after your first "Then."